# Are photos deleted from Telegram chat removed from the Cloud?

Tags: telegram

If I deleted the photos from Telegram chat, would it be deleted from the cloud too? I mean after sending photos to my family, I deleted them from the chat, and I would like to make sure they are deleted from the cloud too, so would they be deleted automatically after I delete from chat history, I deleted them then I cleared the chat.

Answer (score 3):

if the messages have been delivered, then telegram deletes them only if the recipients have [deleted them as well](https://telegram.org/privacy#messages)

> When you delete a message, you delete it from your message history. This means that a copy still stays on the server as part of your partner‘s message history. As soon as your partner deletes it too, it’s gone forever.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. That's a good point for Telegram, respecting privacy.

Comment: @M.SHR If this answer solved your problem, please consider "accepting" it. This will act as a signpost to future readers with the same question. (More in the [Help Center](/help/someone-answers).)

Comment: This answer is not totally accurate. Read my answer.

Answer (score 1):

Since **January 2017** versions (both desktop, web and mobile), **Telegram** allow to delete messages for [everyone](https://desktop.telegram.org/changelog) (this is: *from the cloud*) during 48 hours after writing/sending them. You will be offered an option for this when deleting.

Exceptions: inside [supergroups](https://telegram.org/blog/supergroups), there is a common "chat history" for everyone. So, when deleting (48 hours, just like editing), messages will always disappear for **everybody**.